# Facebook Developer Accout Restriction

Tags: facebook, ads, account, restriction

My account seem to have restricted 2 years back.Last year I tried contacting meta for support but no luck. All it's saying that I need to confirm my identification and failed to do that (Apologies, I wasn't active that time).
If i go to this link - https://www.facebook.com/accountquality, it says No recent issues or any issues, and the options I have can select only last 90 days.
I think the issue was during 2022. I finally managed to find this forum and asking for help. I just need to see the issue in this link and confirm my identification, so that I can advertise on meta platforms.
Thank you

I tried going to this link (https://www.facebook.com/accountquality) to see my issue, but there was no issues mentioned.
I'm expecting to select longer dates, so that I can resolve the issue.

Comment: [so] is for software development and programming questions. Customer service questions should be referred to the relevant vendor. You should be talking to Facebook. See [Why can't I ask customer service questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/14853083)